# How to make colspan attribute applied on specific row not on all rows?

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have a timetable like this:
[table by html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWDdc.png)

all field in all rows have splitted into two columns but i need to make some fields split and some fields no. Something like that
[Edited picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s4ZC.png)

How can i do that?. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan='2'></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: `<td>` stands for **table data**, 
`colspan` stands for **column span**, 
`span` means to extend, 

So, this code is the default `<td colspan='1'></td>`, it means to extend the current table data by 1, which is itself. 

If you code `<td colspan='2'></td>`, it means to extend the current table data by 2, which will take the next right table data and merge into one table data.

Comment: I understand that `colspan='2'` divides the table cell into two parts or whatever the number is, so if  the first row in the table is `<tr><th colspan='2'> </th></tr>` every cell under this `<th>` will split into two parts and then, we type `<tr><td colspan='2'> </td></tr>` as a second row, so this last cell should split into 4 parts. What i misunderstand here.

Comment: `colspan` does not divide/split, it merges cells.

Comment: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) defined the `colsapn`  by  `Use the colspan attribute to make a cell span many columns`. Is that doesn't mean it divide the cell?

Comment: Exactly. `Use the colspan attribute to make a cell span many columns`. **span** means to extend. Using the `colspan` attribute makes the cell extend/merge itself into another cell, not split itself into multiple cells. You can try the concept in Office Word. Make a table row with 4 columns. Then merge the second and third column. When you do that, in html, you have span the second column into the third column to make it into one cell or in code you do `<td colspan='2'></td>` to the second column.